# Setting background color to ActionBar tabs removes divider

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-tabs

I use Android actionbar and tabs and I want to change my tabs background color.
I tried to apply it to the following in my style:

```
Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar
Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabBar
Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView
Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid
```

It works in all cases, but dividers (little bars between each tab) are removed at the well. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a style and apply it to your app or activity:

File `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyHoloLightTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    ....
<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="...">
    <item name="background">@color/actionBarBackgroundColor</item>
    ...
```

File `color.xml`:

```
<color name="actionBarBackgroundColor">#00ff00</color>
```

Apply to app in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/MyHoloLightTheme"
    ...
```